# Compare given string to a result

Tags: c

i'm currently programming a Bulls and Cows program and I'm trying to figure out how to compare a given string with the result I have.
I'm pasting my code here so you'll understand better.
On the code: I have a char test that is the given string and i have several results. around 1296 results. What i want it to do is to compare the result to the char test and tell me if it's the same or not.(equal or not). I hope i didn't miss any additional information. Please let me know if I did. Thanks :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void initialize(int poss[1296][4]);

int main()
{
    int table[1296][4];
    char str[5];
    char tmp[5];

    int i, j, k;
    int bull = 0;
    int cow = 0;
    char test[7]={"2 B 0 C"};

    initialize(table);
    printf("Enter 4 digits: ");

    scanf("%s", str);

    for (i=0; i<1296; i++)  // building this table
    {
        strcpy(tmp, str);   // copying string

        for (j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            for (k=0; k<4; k++)
            {
                if (table[i][j]==tmp[k]-'0' && j==k)    // gets the string as an integer
                {
                    tmp[k] = -1;
                    bull++;
                    break;
                }
                else if (table[i][j]==tmp[k]-'0' && j!=k)
                {
                    tmp[k] = -1;
                    cow++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //printf ("Number: %d%d%d%d, Input: %s\n",table[i][0], table[i][1], table[i][2],     table[i][3], str);
        printf ("%d B %d C\n\n", bull, cow);
        bull = 0;
        cow = 0;
    }
}

void initialize(int poss[1296][4])
{
    int i=0;
    int j, k=0;
    int m;

    while (i<=5)
    {
        for (j=0; j<216 ; j++)
        {
            poss[k][0]=i;
            k++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    k=0;
    i=0;
    j=0;

    while (k<1296)
    {
        for (m=0; m<6; m++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<6; j++)
            {
                for (i=0; i<36 ; i++)
                {
                    poss[k][1]=j;
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    k=0;
    i=0;
    j=0;
    m=0;

    while (k<1296)
    {
        for (j=0; j<6; j++)
        {
            for (i=0; i<6; i++)
            {
                poss[k][2]=j;
                k++;
            }
        }

    }

    k=0;
    i=0;
    j=0;
    m=0;

    while (k<1296)
    {
        for (i=0; i<6; i++)
        {
            poss[k][3]=i;
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a function `strcmp` to compare strings. you can do it manually also.

Comment: There is a function **strcmp** for comparing 2 strings case-sensitive and **stricmp** for comparing 2 strings case-insensitive. You can modify your code to use those 2 functions.

Comment: okay yes but how can i compare my string with the result in the printf?

Comment: Building on @cirosantilli 's answer, instead of using printf to output a result, use it to store the character string to another variable (eg: temp_string) and then compare that with what you want. The example code here - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/ should give you ideas.

Comment: if i understand it correctly using sprintf stores my result as a string and then I can apply the compare?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, I think there are 2 easy ways to test:

1.

```
if ((bull == test[0] - '0') && (cow == test[4] - '0'))
    // strings are equal
```

2.

```
char buffer[8];
sprintf(tempString, "%d B %d C", bull, cow);
if (strcmp(tempString, test) == 0)
    // strings are equal
printf("%s\n\n", buffer);
```

I would suggest the first method, however or even better, add these:

```
int testBull = test[0] - '0';
int testCow = test[4] - '0';
```

And test with them rather than calculating them at each step.